# DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'nativrd2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, dll

I recently upgraded .NET framework from 4.0 to 4.5.1 in my .NET MVC Application. I have a wcf web service in our project, now my IIS 7 doesn't seem to like my wcf service anymore. When I try to connect to it, using soapUI or by url in the browser, it will just reroute to my regular loginpage.

I get this error in the eventlog.

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/60493796
 Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'nativrd2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 2852
```

Thanks

Comment: I have put detailed explanation in answer below

Comment: Does your WCF service have any dependency on the nativrd2.dll? Also make sure that you have change the app pool to the correct one on IIS to make sure that it runs without any problem

Comment: No it does not. I've never even heard about the .dll before. The IIS hasn't changed lately at all, the app pool is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I wasn't clear try to embed resource 'nativrd2.dll'

you have to find resource file through VS then right click on filename -> properties -> Build Action -> Embeded resource

Comment: No it is not an embeded resource

Comment: I have put detailed explanation in answer above